# Page titles from product name

Tags: commerce, 7

I've installed the Drupal commerce module, and made an article with some products. So I've got this [node:field-product:title] title for the article in the Page title module, but it shows all product titles. I need only the selected product from list in the page title.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The problem there is the "product" changes each time you select a new attribute combination. Would the page title need to change on ajax refresh?

Comment: yea. i think so. i can't see another way. only refreshing of page every time. i'm not good in ajax. can you tell me how it must look?

Comment: and, by the way. is it bad for SEO? using ajax titles for product pages?

Comment: It does not have to ruin your SEO (as long as google can access each individual page), but I would reload the whole page rather then changing the title. (It's like clicking a link from a drop-down.) That would work more like a user would expect it.

Comment: it's reloading the div, shown on the screen. but it's commerce field catalog.